# Displaying long string in pygame

Tags: pygame

If I want to display long string using pygame normally the part of string will go outside pygame screen depending on font size, so is it possible to show long string by scrolling in pygame like we see in news channel moving text on bottom of TV screen?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Here is a draft on how it should work.

Create a class that will hold a surface where you will draw your text.
This class should also contain the current sprites as well as a list of text to be written.
Now you create these methods:

Init method

```
should put the first text int the current_sprite list.
```

Draw method

```
draws all sprites in the current sprite list.
```

An update method that does this:

```
For each current sprite:
   moveUp
   checkIf out of bounds -> if true remove from current sprites
   checkIf the first sprite has crossed the y offset, 
   so you can spawn a new sprite at the bottom. 
   When you spawn a new one, you should increment the counter responsible for
   remembering which text to create next.
```